Paste error in grid view when copying value into a SharePoint list lookup column
I have a question regarding lookup columns on microsoft lists. I used to be able to copy and paste information into the lookup column as long as the written value matched the registered options in the lookup coming from another list. Now, to copy and paste, I need to insert the ID from the original list instead of the data value itself.
So if in list 1 I have a column with 3 rows: pants, shirt, and cap. I register this column in list 2 as a lookup column. If I copy from Excel and paste the exact name “shirt,” the lookup column will not recognize it; it will only work if I insert the ID of that row. No one memorizes the ID to copy and paste in bulk in the GRID view.
